# How long does it typically take for popular anime to be dubbed in English?

Tags: anime-production, voice-acting

There are a lot of new seasons of anime coming out soon, and I was wondering how long does it take for popular anime to get dubbed in English?

If it helps, the two main ones I am thinking of are Sword Art Online: Ordinal Scale and Attack on Titan Season 2.

Comment: AoT's second season looks to be slated for Spring 2017 and SAO's movie is coming in February.  Dubbing a series is different to dubbing a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on who has the western rights to it. If it's Funimation it'll either be a broadcast dub then that'll be 3-5 weeks for the first dub episode to air or they'll dub it for the home release roughly a year later. For the others (Sentai, Aniplex etc..) it'll be roughly a year later for the home release, if it even gets a dub.